# How can I set up EntityFrameworkCore fluid api for a foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have these classes:

```
public class Field
{ 
    public double FieldId { get; set; }
    public List<Media> Media { get; set; } 
}

public class Media
{
    public double MediaId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set up the foreign key using the EntityFrameworeCore fluid api.

Can someone give me suggestions on how to do this?

Also do I need to have some kind of reference to Field in the Media class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying "fluid api", i think you mean Fluent Api.
Looks like you are trying to make One-To Many Relationship. You can try something like this

```
public class Field
{ 
    public double FieldId { get; set; }
    public List<Media> Media { get; set; } 
}

public class Media
{
    public double MediaId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Field Field { get; set; }
}
```

Then you add this line to your OnModelCreating Method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Field>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Media)
        .WithOne(e => e.Field);
```

EF CORE will automatically generate shadow property for foreign key.